# Bug when using contact form

Tags: php, forms

When I choose the Contact page I get "BUG: couldnot get Form object contact" If I do a return, then all functions on the page.

I know the line in the validation code is what I'm getting

I have not figured out my problem. 
Sure it is simple to a younger code person.

This is the actual page:
http://p3africa.net/contact.html

Any help appreciated. Thought I gave the from an ID

Comment: The problem lies in an `iframe` you have in that page, related to Captcha most probably. The API or API secret key may be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Due to my low reputation I can't comment on your question.
I think it might be you are missing the name of your form in the validation (happened to me once).
I think it would be great help for anyone willing to help you if you post your code.